# Erlang pattern not matching, but correct, what to do?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

i have an crazy problem with pattern matching in erlang:

My receive block:

```
...
receive
    {set_val,Val} -> 
        log("got: ~p",[Val]);

    Any ->
        log("~p is an unknown command",[Any])
end.
```

What I send:

```
...
{myreceive,myreceive@workstation} ! {set_val,100}
```

What in my Log appears:

```
{set_val,100} is an unknown command
```

how come, that the first pattern does not match? (and how to make it matching :/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possibility I see is that Val is already bound in your function to a value different from 100.

Comment: thats it ... so easy but yeah thats it

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work as expected.

```
1> spawn(fun() -> receive {set_val, Val} -> io:format("got: ~p~n", [Val]); Any -> io:format("~p is an unknown command",[Any]) end end) ! {set_val,100}.
got: 100
{set_val,100}
```

As [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635979/pascal) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24293525/49197) there have to be variable `Val` already bound to something different from `100`.